# I need a all in one lisp reference

Tags: common-lisp

I'm a python/c/c++ programmer, I'm using emacs, and I read hackers & painters, and I read SICP, and I'm starting reading practical common lisp, but the problem is, I need a library reference as python documentation do(also with how to communicate with C library), so I can actual using lisp in real life. any links? (current focus on common-lisp)

and, after I can really use lisp, how can I learn from others, and dive into the lisp community?

maybe a total lisp reference contains all, but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Common Lisp Quick Reference](http://clqr.berlios.de/) gives you a nice overview of the core language. It can be printed to small booklets.

For things like communication to C etc. you need to use the manuals of the libraries (say, CFFI or the specific FFI of the CL implementation) or implementations.

Which Lisp implementation(s) are you using?

- [CLISP Implementation Notes](http://www.gnu.org/software/clisp/impnotes/)
- [SBCL manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/)
- full [LispWorks manuals in HTML, PDF and PS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/index.html)
- full [Allegro CL manuals](http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/8.2/doc/contents.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Common Lisp HyperSpec?](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/)

It covers all of ANSI Common Lisp, but will not tell you "how to communicate with C library" since that is implementation dependent.

Comment: And, crucially, Common Lisp is a multi-implementation (and multi-OS) standard. Python is primarily single-implementation, but still multi-OS.

Comment: this document is badly decorated (maybe it is created long ago), and read it confused me.. maybe I sould finish practical common lisp first.. the question is till open for further answers.

Comment: If you are confused by the HyperSpec, you might try CLtL2 (CommonLisp the Language 2nd Edition, by Guy Steele) http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/cltl2.html